# Print newlines (linebreaks) with Fat Free Framework

Tags: php, html, fat-free-framework

I have a textarea which posts and saves a message in MySql
I try to print it in a div with fatfree as
{{@note}} or {{@note | raw}}. Both shows the text as single line. I've checked in phpMyAdmin that the value is saved with linebreaks.
What should I do to print this text as-is with line breaks?

Comment: HTML doesn't care about line breaks. Convert them to `<br>`s.

Comment: How should i convert them from the database output? I can't see anything (such as \n, \nr etc.) in database with phpmyadmin too.

Answer (score 1):

```
<p style="white-space: pre-line">multi-line text</p>
```

This works! It is not specific to fat free, or PHP.

Comment: You can also try {{@note | nl2br,raw}}